# segmentation fault while calling a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I have this function where after a while of execution there occurs a segmentation fault which seems to be occuring due to a function call inside it.

```cpp
void dfs(struct node* gptr,int start)
{
    // printf("\ntest 1");
    struct node* temp;
    struct adjListNode* adj;
    int item;
    push(start);
    // printf("\ntest 2::%d",top);
    while(top!=-1)
    {
        // printf("\ntest 3");
        item=pop();
        printf("\n%d",searchVisit(item));
        if(searchVisit(item)==0)  \\searchVisit is the function call which seems to be the problem
        {
            //printf("\ntest 4");
            printf("%d ",item);
            addVisit(item);
            temp=gptr;
            while((temp!=NULL)&&(temp->data!=item))
                temp=temp->link;
            adj=temp->alink;
            while(adj!=NULL)
            {
                //printf("\ntest 5");
                push(adj->data);
                adj=adj->next;
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```

I'm getting only two statements(test 1,test 2) printed when calling searchVisit..But when I tried commenting it out the third test too gets printed.Is there a way to fix this?Given below are the two functions which are called upon from the previous function dfs.

```cpp
int searchVisit(int i)
{
    struct adjListNode *ptr;
    ptr=visit;
    int flag;
    flag=0;
    do{
    if(ptr->data==i)
    {
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
    ptr=ptr->next; 
    }while(ptr!=NULL);

    return flag;
}

void addVisit(int item)
{
    struct adjListNode *el;
    el->data=item;
    el->next=NULL;
    if(visit==NULL)
        visit=el;
    else
        visit->next=el;
 return;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever call `searchVisit` with `visit` being `NULL`? Because your code doesn't handle that case correctly.

Comment: It can be hard to learn to use debuggers when you are new at programming, but it is worth it! A debugger will explain exactly where and why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
  struct adjListNode *el;
  el->data=item;
  el->next=NULL;
```

you don't allocate any memory to `el`

Further, the `addVisit` doesn't add new elements corretly. Your code can only hold 2 elements because you always add the new element to `visit->next`.

You need something like

```
void addVisit(int item)
{
  struct adjListNode *el;
  el = malloc(sizeof *el);
  if (!el) exit(1);  // Out of memory
  el->data=item;
  el->next=visit;
  visit = el;
}
```

This will add new elements in the front of the linked list.

BTW: Using a global variable like `visit` is a bad idea. Pass it as function argument.

Comment: Sorry but it is still showing segmentation fault

Comment: Idk but I'm still not getting it right 

Comment: The complete program could be found here:https://repl.it/@SheldonC/Graph#main.c